# How to triangulate Points from a Single Camera multiple Images?

Tags: c++, opencv, 3d, camera

I have a single calibrated camera pointing at a checkerboard at different locations with Known

1. **Camera Intrinsics**. fx,fy,cx,cy
2. **Distortion Co-efficients** K1,K2,K3,T1,T2,etc..
3. **Camera Rotation & Translation** (R,T) from IMU
   [image]

After Undistortion, I have computed Point correspondence of checkerboard points in all the images with a known camera-to-camera Rotation and Translation vectors.

How can I estimate the 3D points of the checkerboard in all the images?

I think OpenCV has a function to do this but I'm not able to understand how to use this!

1) [cv::sfm::triangulatePoints](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d0/dbd/group__triangulation.html#ga211c855276b3084f3bbd8b2d9161dc74)

2) [triangulatePoints](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.8/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#triangulatepoints)

How to compute the 3D Points using OpenCV?

Comment: Balaji-R, did you found solution?

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the matched points form the image you can use [findFundamentalMat()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.8/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#Mat%20findFundamentalMat(InputArray%20points1,%20InputArray%20points2,%20int%20method,%20double%20param1,%20double%20param2,%20OutputArray%20mask)) to get the fundamental matrix. Keep in mind you need at least 7 matched points to do this. If you have more then 8 points CV_FM_RANSAC might be the best option.

Then use [cv::sfm::projectionsFromFundamental()](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d15/group__fundamental.html#gae29b41e17673893a3fb0ed6c38f2d23e) to find the projection matrix for each image, check if the projection matrix is valid (ex.check if the points are in-front of the camera).

then feed the projections and the points it into cv::sfm::triangulatePoints().

Hope this helps :)

**Edit**

The rotation and translation matrix are needed to change reference frames because the camera moves in SFM. The reference frame is at the position of the camera. Transforms are needed to make sure the position of the points a coherent(under the same reference frame which is usually the reface frame of the camera in the first image), so all the points are in the same coordinate system.

IE. To relate the point gathered by the second frame to the first frame, the third to second frame and so on.

So basically you can use the R and T vector to construct a transform matrix for each frame and multiplying it with your points to put them in the reface frame of the camera in the first frame.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer! This is exactly what cv::sfm::reconstruct function does! http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/db5/group__reconstruction.html#ga279c084302ae1d7541d458e4b23fabd3 But what I don't understand is How my Camera R & T vectors are used in this? I already know the R & T of my camera here! How can I use this to find the Position of the Checker board?

Comment: From my limited understanding of the 8- point algorithm, it does not use the rotation and translation matrix directly. #NotSure I will try to enplane this in the edit

Comment: If you wish to learn more try reading this book "Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision"